# C++ conditional compilation for a class with an optional dependency

Tags: c++, conditional-compilation

I have a `Rainfall` class whose implementation depends on [NetCDF](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/), but the project should be compilable with or without NetCDF.  Can I achieve conditional compilation without sprinkling preprocessor directives all over the code?  What's the best practice in this situation?

**rainfall.hpp**

```cpp
#pragma once

class Rainfall {
public:
    // several constructors, methods, and destructor
private:
    // several methods and variables
};
```

**rainfall.cpp**

```cpp
#include "rainfall.hpp"
#include <netcdf.h>

// concrete implementation of class members
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "rainfall.hpp"
#include <stdio>
#include <cstdlib>

void main_loop();

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (user_wants_rainfall) {
#ifndef NETCDF
        std::cerr << "Rainfall not available: project was not compiled with NetCDF\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
#endif
    }

    main_loop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void main_loop() {
    Rainfall rainfall;
    while (t < end_time) {
        if (user_wants_rainfall) rainfall.apply_to_simulation();
        t++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could link against a dummy library that defines all the NetCDF entry points that you use as stubs.

Comment: [Null_object_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) might interest you.

Comment: It will be depend on code, changes required and complexity of code. I have gone through with the huge code which is maintaining the preprocessor to enable/disable features. I feel you can go with preprocessor as looks it's not many place.

Comment: @Jarod42 that's the pattern I've gone with: the makefile compiles either rainfall.cpp or rainfall_stub.cpp, with both defining an implementation of rainfall.hpp.  The only snag is remembering to update both files when adding new class members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a project that can be compiled with or without a specified library, you need to have two implementations

**rainfall_netcdf.cpp**

```
#ifdef USE_NETCDF
#include "rainfall.hpp"
#include <netcdf.h>
//your definitions using your lib
#endif //USE_NETCDF
```

**rainfall.cpp**

```
#ifndef USE_NETCDF
#include "rainfall.hpp"
//your definitions without your lib
#endif //USE_NETCDF
```

And in your project, you must define the USE_NETCDF macro if you want to use this lib. For example in visual studio : >properties >C/C++ >Preprocessor >Preprocessor definitions.